# Is there a way to combine a SQL column with a LIKE

Tags: sql, mysql

What I mean is this...

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_a LIKE %column_b%
```

So that the content of column_a is searched in column_b. And when there is the word 'car' in column_a, and the words 'car parts' in column_b that would be a match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the CONCAT function like so

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_a LIKE CONCAT('%',column_b,'%')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_a LIKE CONCAT('%', column_b , '%')
```